# Treeview Territory Structure via VF page

Tags: visualforce

Can anybody share the vf page and controller code for Treeview structure for territories?Would be really helpful..Or atleast guide me how to traverse

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the appexchange product "Inline Account Hierarchy":
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016chCEAQ

I think this is doing pretty close to what you would like and should give you an idea on how to approach this. It's unmanaged so you have full access to the code.

I've not done anything like this with territories so cannot forewarn of any "gotchas".